# cocoa compiled app resources keep folder structure?

Tags: xcode, cocoa

Generally when you build an cocoa application, it will put all of your resources in the Contents/Resource directory inside of your application bundle. Is there a way to have this keep the same structure as they are actually defined in the source?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, you should create not groups but actual directory references in your project.